# What's the point of the Release vs Debug dropdown in Visual Studio if changes don't take hold unless you Publish?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have web config transformations set up that work fine when I publish to something like Azure.  But selecting between Release and Debug locally seems worthless if the web.config transformations don't actually get applied when running locally.

Is there any way to get these transformations to apply when I click "run"?  If not, what's the point of having that dropdown?  I'm genuinely curious, not asking rhetorically.

Comment: Do you mean the dropdown where you can select which configuration you want to build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea for web.config transforms is that you have some settings that change between environments.  For example, you might have a local development connection string, and you'll always use that when running/debugging locally.  When you publish to your production server, though, you want to use your production DB.  Debug vs. Release configurations at build time just change some settings in *how* your project is *built* (most commonly, how debug symbols are generated or what compiler optimizations are enabled), whereas web.config transforms are changing the *content* of what gets deployed (in web.config).

If you do want to apply the web.config transforms locally on F5, there are extensions that allow you to do so.  [Slow Cheetah](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) is one such.  However, in many cases, you probably don't need this as your web.config will stay mostly constant whenever you run locally.

Comment: Slow Cheetah is EXACTLY what I was looking for.  Thanks Jimmy.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all IDEs have release and debug modes, in the debug mode, the code is compiled using debug flags and not so much optimization, i.e., some relation between the built program and the source code is kept, in this way you can run your code using a debugger, it is a tool that allows you to track and control the flow of execution of your application, for example the value stored in some variable in some situation in your code, this in order to expose semantic problems that your application may have, i.e., when your code is not actually doing what you expect it to be doing (most of the people does this using print statements everywhere at least once).

The release mode is aimed to produce an optimized version of your application, without debugging/profiling flags.

Notice that this have nothing to do with debug mode of web applications, where we set automated views to show more information when a run time error occurs, it just have to do with optimization or debugging of the actual program running underneath. So setting debug or release mode may not change whether a web application shows tracebacks or not, but it certainly changes the performance of the application running locally in your server.

Regards.